# Where is the RAM located in ASUS VivoBook K551LN?

Tags: memory, windows-8.1

I bought this laptop recently, and tried to change to 2x4 GB RAM sticks that I had bought (which is in my previous laptop now). I unscrewed the case at the bottom but I couldn't find any RAM slots, so I thought it might be buried deep inside the laptop components.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that laptop only has one slot available, with another 4 GB soldered on . . . so you can add an 8GB module to get to 12, or you'll be able to put one of your 4GB modules in to get to 8.

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions for this in the [User Manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/S551LN/0409_E8632_A.pdf)

I have included some excerpts in case the site goes down.

1.
Shut down your Notebook PC and disconnect all cables and other
peripherals.

2.
Put your Notebook PC on a flat, clean and stable surface.
3.
Unscrew and remove the back cover.

4.
Touch any metal part of the Notebook PC to discharge yourself of
static electricity.
5.
Remove the DIMM metal shield
[image]

6.Gently pull apart the clips that hold the DIMM in place (A) then
pull the memory module to remove it from the slot (B)
7. Align and insert the new DIMM into the slot (A) and press it
down (B), until it is securely seated in place
[image]

8.Align the DIMM metal shield’s notches with the metal braces
surrounding the DIMM slot then reattach the DIMM metal shield
[image]

9.Replace the screws and back panel you removed in step 3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll find a time to try out this method, and will get back to you whether I have installed the 8 GB RAM successfully or not.

Comment: Did this answer work?

Comment: Unfortunately my new 4GB stick didn't work.