# Where is the RAM located in a Vivobook Flip 14?

Tags: memory, asus-laptop

According to the specs, this Vivobook has 4GB on-board and 4GB SO-DIMM RAM, upgradable to 8GB. Unlike [the solution to a similar Asus question,](https://superuser.com/questions/776423/where-is-the-ram-located-in-asus-vivobook-k551ln) the user manual does not explain how to locate the removable RAM. Where is it?

[image: Internals of an Asus Vivobook Flip 14]

Comment: You probably need a more specific model number. There are several 'flip 14' models.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively easy to find using Google image search. Here:

[image]

Also see https://youtu.be/QEs4eMyTrso